# Unable to use AnyObject in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I don't understand an inch of how the AnyObject type in Swift is supposed to work. I am loading a Plist file into a NSDictionary instance in my Swift code (not shown here). Later I try to use some of the values from the Plist file in a UIPickerView:

```
// Trying to extract the first fruit
let fruitKeys = fruits.allKeys
let fruitKey = fruitKeys[0]

// This is another NSDictionary
let fruit = fruits.objectForKey(fruitKey)

// Getting a property of a fruit                
let nutritions = fruit.objectForKey("nutritions") 
let nutritionKeys = nutritions.allKeys
```

However I am not able to get the keys of a fruit by calling `nutritions.allKeys`. I get `Could not find member allKeys`. However, which part of the documentation have I misunderstood? I read that you can call any objective c method on an instance of `AnyObject`. Why do I need to cast or to some other magic here?

Should I cast everything to their real types? Or should I use AnyObject??

Comment: "fruit.objectForKey("nutritions")" returns an id, so there should definitely be a typecast to NSDictionary or Dictionary.

Comment: you can call any objective c method  by bridging:- 
fruits.bridgeToObjectiveC.allKeys

Comment: But should AnyObject types always be casted? You should never call methods on the instance of type AnyObject without casting first?

Comment: you need to cast it properly, regarding `let nutritions = fruit.objectForKey("nutritions")` makes `nutritions` as `AnyObject` and that has not such method like `allKeys`. it is defined in `NSDictionary` only.

Comment: @holex But from the docs: `You can also call any Objective-C method and access any property without casting to a more specific class type. `. Isn't that exactly what I am doing here? Could you explain it for me why it doesn't/shouldn't work?

Comment: It works for me (on the latest Xcode beta), except the line `let fruitKey = fruitKeys[0]`

Comment: @LuckyLuke, what you are doing here (implicitly) is this: `let nutritions: AnyObject = fruit.objectForKey("nutritions")`, and the `AnyObject` has not such method like `allKeys`, because the method you called returns an `id` only not `NSDictionary`. (reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/objectForKey:), this is represented by `AnyObject` in _Swift_. I'm not sure there is anymore explanation necessary, but please tell me your doubt, if there is still any.

Comment: The quote is from https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html under the id compatibility section. I don't get what Apple is trying to say here then?

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes you would generally want to cast to your defined type, here's how I would write it:

```
let fruitKeys = fruits.allKeys as [String]
let fruitKey = fruitKeys[0]

let fruit = fruits[fruitKey] as NSDictionary

let nutritions = fruit["nutritions"] as NSDictionary
let nutritionKeys = nutritions.allKeys
```

As I already mentioned in my comment, a possible change to your code would be:

```
let fruitKeys = fruits.allKeys
let fruitKey = fruitKeys[0]

let fruit = fruits.objectForKey(fruitKey)

let nutritions = fruit.objectForKey("nutritions")
let nutritionKeys : AnyObject? = nutritions.allKeys
```

I omitted downcasting every value because I saw it as pointless, so you might encounter some warnings, but it will work.

Comment: Okey, so you don't use AnyObject objects directly normally? However, why doesn't it work without casting. Doesn't the documentation state that you can call any objective c method on an AnyObject instance without casting?

Comment: The last line in your code is the culprit, try changing it to:
"let nutritionKeys : AnyObject? = nutritions.allKeys". For some reason it finds "allKeys" as an ambiguous method, and the only cure I found is to downcast it to AnyObject or AnyObject? (depending on your expected result). I have no explanation on why this is required.

Comment: "Doesn't the documentation state that you can call any objective c method on an AnyObject instance without casting?" No, that is not quite what the documentation says. And in any case `allKeys` is a property, not a method, which is a different kettle of fish. — Basically AnyObject is just a means of moving ids back and forth across the bridge. You don't want to be trying to use it internally in Swift; it will fight you every inch of the way.

Comment: @matt Would you bother writing what Apple is trying to say then so I could learn then? And does this mean that you always should cast the AnyObject?

Comment: I always cast an AnyObject as soon as it comes across the bridge from the runtime, yes, unless there is some good reason why I can't. For example, you can't cast an NSArray or NSDictionary that contains multiple types, because Swift doesn't allow that. But then in that case I might feed that data into some other Swift format so that I can work with it.

Comment: @matt Okey, and what does the documentation try to say about AnyObject and method calls then? I clearly misunderstand it

Comment: It says "You can also call any Objective-C method and access any property without casting to a more specific class type." So you didn't misunderstand it! And this does work in seed 4 if you keep casting away type.